# assign NSMutableArray with @property and 'copy' attribute

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm following an official tutorial *Your second iOS App:Storyboard* and it told me to declare a property **masterBirdSightingList** like this(just a specific example and not necessary to know the context) :

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableArray *masterBirdSightingList;
```

Note that there's an attribute **copy**. and then synthesize this property :

```
@synthesize masterBirdSightingList = _masterBirdSightingList;
```

And next there's one init method which made me confused :

```
- (void)initializeDefaultDataList {
NSMutableArray *sightingList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
self.masterBirdSightingList = sightingList;
[self addBirdSightingWithName:@"Pigeon" location:@"Everywhere"];
}
```

Definitely sightingList is allocated for spaces and then it's assigned to the masterBirdSightingList property. The property has a **copy** attribute, though. it means the instance variable **_masterBirdSightingList** would be allocated for another space to preserve stuffs from **sightingList**. Why? Why not directly allocate space for the property like this :

```
self.masterBirdSightingList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Comment: I wonder know the statement self.masterBirdSightingList = sightingList is just a simple copy operation that only copies the reference OR it will allocate a new space to store the content? thx

Comment: Something worth watching out for: generally, a "mutable" object’s -copy method will return the non-mutable variant (in your case, an NSArray). In order to prevent an exception, you have to write the setter method yourself to call -mutableCopy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Objective-C, the `copy` attribute in a property means the setter synthesized will look like this:

```
-(void)setMasterBirdSightingList:(NSMutableArray*)newValue
{
    if (_masterBirdSightingList == newValue) return;
//  NSMutableArray* oldValue = _masterBirdSightingList;
    _masterBirdSightingList = [newValue copy];
//  [oldValue release];    // <-- not applicable in ARC.
}
```

and that dot syntax will always be translated to

```
[self setMasterBirdSightingList:sightingList];
```

regardless of the attribute of the property.

The "allocated for another space to preserve stuffs from sightingList" stuff is done via the `-copy` method. The way you pass the argument to the setter's `newValue` parameter is irrelevant.

---

**Edit**: As [@David](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10724866/assign-nsmutablearray-with-property-and-copy-attribute/10725055#comment13930680_10724866) mentioned in the comment, the `-copy` method of a mutable type returns an immutable object. You have to override the setter to call `-mutableCopy` instead. See [What's the best way to use Obj-C 2.0 Properties with mutable objects, such as NSMutableArray?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/816720/whats-the-best-way-to-use-obj-c-2-0-properties-with-mutable-objects-such-as-ns).

Comment: I would hope the compare would be with `isEqual:`.

Comment: @HotLicks: No they should not be compared with `-isEqual:`. The `==` exists mainly to avoid double-release when `-copy` returns the same value (possible with immutable types) and you are using `self.foo = self.foo`.

Comment: I looked at the tutorial, and it does include instructions on overriding the setter to preserve mutability.