# NSMutableDictionary is immutable

Tags: ios, immutability, nsmutabledictionary

In myClass.h, I have

```
@property (copy, atomic) NSMutableDictionary *thisParticularWordList;
```

In myClass.m I populate thisParticularWordList as follows:

```
theSubview.thisParticularWordList = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary: someDictionary];
```

In the variables view of xcode I see, that the property of this instance is indeed populated.

Elsewhere in my code, I try to do this:

```
[self.thisParticularWordList removeObjectForKey:self.theKey];
```

but somehow, self.thisParticularWordList turned into a non-mutable NSDictionary.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: how can you say, this `NSMutableDictionary `  turned into a non-mutable one?

Comment: The app crashes on that line with the error "-[__NSDictionaryI removeObjectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7c3c3600'"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because of the `copy` attribute of your property. Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11762317/why-theres-no-mutablecopy-qualifier-in-objective-c).

A solution would be to make the property `strong` and then when assigning it, you would do `self.yourProperty = [yourDictionary mutableCopy];`.

Or even `[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary: someDictionary];` as that also creates a new dictionary.

---

A whole code example demonstrating the fix:

*MyClass.h*

```
@property (strong, atomic) NSMutableDictionary *thisParticularWordList;
```

*MyClass.m*

```
theSubview.thisParticularWordList = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary: someDictionary];
```

Then this will work after assigning:

```
[self.thisParticularWordList removeObjectForKey:self.theKey];
```

Comment: Thanks! Changing 'copy' into 'strong' did the trick. I have to admit that my knowledge of attributes is wobbly. I'm now studying http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9859719/objective-c-declared-property-attributes-nonatomic-copy-strong-weak

Comment: @Sjakelien That is a great SO question, be sure to read that. Attributes can make a big impact on your code, inculding memory management, code safety and even thread safety. If you found my answer sufficient, can you please mark it as the correct one? :)

Comment: I know this is not the place for questions, but how come that Xcode gives a lot of helpful hints, but doesn't suggest that I should use 'strong' in this case? Are there situations where you would want to have a 'copy'-attribute to an NSMutableDictionary?

Answer (score 0):

you need to be worry about this particular line:

```
@property (copy, atomic) NSMutableDictionary * thisParticularWordList;
```

because the property's *setter* copies your mutable collection and makes it **immutable** one; that is why you get the crash later.

---

you may need to consider to keep a strong reference only instead of copying it, like:

```
@property (strong, atomic) NSMutableDictionary * thisParticularWordList;
```

Comment: This looks like the same answer which was answered 10 minutes before.  What's the point of the duplication?

Comment: it seems to me, the accepted answer copies my actual explanation of the situation.

Comment: Copies it?  But it was entered 10 minutes before yours?

Comment: that answer was a messy _gibberish_ only to me, not a real solution or explanation.

Comment: OK so first you say that it copies your answer (even though it was entered before yours) and now it's gibberish.  I have to disagree with both those points.

Comment: yes, when I posted my answer that was nothing about showing how the property should be defined, and after 3 minutes I posted mine – magically – it appears the same concept in that answer as I presented.

Comment: Wow - please check the edit - all that was added was the code sample; I don't see anything added to the explanation.  Anyway nevermind.

Comment: their explanation is pasted from the linked answer only; I'm not chasing here upvotes but I'm committed to present easily readable and understandable answers for the actual problems; and in my view the answer you referred was nothing like that on any level. anyway, nevermind.

Comment: I am sorry, but your answer isn't in any way more or less readable than mine. I don't see why you think I copied everything from you, as I answered first and there isn't really any other way of declaring a property so it doesn't look the same as in your answer.

Comment: Wow... I'm kind of sorry that I asked this question.

Comment: @Sjakelien, it is not about you – it is about the answer's quality only.