# NSMutableDictionary crashes with "mutating message sent to immutable object"

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, nsmutabledictionary

I have a class that has a `NSMutableDictionary` as a property:

```
@interface Alibi : NSObject <NSCopying>
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableDictionary * alibiDetails;
@end
```

With the following constructor:

```
- (Alibi *)init
{
    self = [super init];
    _alibiDetails = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    return self;
}
```

and copy method:

```
- (Alibi *)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
    Alibi *theCopy = [[Alibi alloc] init];
    theCopy.alibiDetails = [self.alibiDetails mutableCopy];    
    return theCopy;
}
```

When I try to call `setObject:ForKey:` I get a runtime error `mutating method sent to immutable object`.

I have the `Alibi` object declared in the view controller as `@property (copy, nonatomic) Alibi * theAlibi;` and I initialize it with `self.theAlibi = [[Alibi alloc] init];` in `viewDidLoad`.

The line which crashes is:

```
NSString * recipient;
recipient = @"Boss";
[self.theAlibi.alibiDetails setObject:recipient forKey:@"Recipient"];
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong here. I am coding for iOS 5 on iPhone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a 'copy' property, which means exactly that - your NSMutableDictionary will get the  -copy method called and return a regular NSDictionary before being assigned to the synthesized instance variable. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/816720/whats-the-best-way-to-use-obj-c-2-0-properties-with-mutable-objects-such-as-ns) provides some information on some of your options as to solving this.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completing this thread I will include my revised `Alibi` class below, this works as I require it to. If anyone notices any memory leaks or other issues, that would be appreciated.

```
@implementation Alibi

NSMutableDictionary *_details;

- (Alibi *)init
{
    self = [super init];
    _details = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    return self;
}

- (NSMutableDictionary *)copyDetails
{
    return [_details mutableCopy];
}

- (NSMutableDictionary *)setDetails:(NSMutableDictionary *)value
{
    _details = value;
    return value;
}

- (void)addDetail:(id)value forKey:(id)key
{
    [_details setObject:value forKey:key];
}

- (id)getDetailForKey:(id)key
{
    return [_details objectForKey:key];
}

- (Alibi *)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
    Alibi *theCopy = [[Alibi alloc] init];

    theCopy.serverId = [self.serverId copyWithZone:zone];
    theCopy.user = [self.user copyWithZone:zone];
    theCopy.startTime = [self.startTime copyWithZone:zone];
    theCopy.endTime = [self.endTime copyWithZone:zone];
    [theCopy setDetails:[self copyDetails]];

    return theCopy;
}

@end
```