# getting NSMutableArray Property filled with enumerated values

Tags: ios, properties, nsmutablearray, enumerated-types

Attempting to get an enumerated value by an index from a NSMutableArray property that is filled with enumerated values.

all I wanted is to set a dynamic property and get set back within class instance.

thus,
I coded a clear example that expose of problem.

**Problem is this. WriteByType method in example never gets correct value.
it should log "You Get Right Arrow" but it doesn't**

```
//----------------------------------------------------------
//  CCMyClass.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

typedef enum {
    aLeft,
    aRight
} Arrow;

@interface CCMyClass : NSObject
{
    NSMutableArray *_arrowsPkg;
}
@property(nonatomic,copy) NSMutableArray *arrowsPkg;
@property (nonatomic)int nextPkgIndex;
-(void)GetItemOne;
@end
//-------------------------------------------------------------
//  CCMyClass.m
#import "CCMyClass.h"

@implementation CCMyClass
@synthesize arrowsPkg=_arrowsPkg;

-(void)WriteByType:(Arrow)AArrow
{
switch (AArrow) {
    case aLeft:
        NSLog(@"You Get Left Arrow");
        break;
    case aRight:
        NSLog(@"You Get Right Arrow");
        break;
    }
}

-(void)GetItemOne
{
    Arrow a =(Arrow)[[self arrowsPkg]objectAtIndex:1];
    [self WriteByType:a];

}
@end
//---------------USAGE EXAMPLE----------------------------------------------
//  CCAppDelegate.m
- (IBAction)btn1Clicked:(id)sender {

    CCMyClass *c1=[[CCMyClass alloc]init];
    NSNumber *v1=[NSNumber numberWithInt:aLeft];
    NSNumber *v2=[NSNumber numberWithInt:aRight];

    NSMutableArray *arr1=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:v1,v2, nil];
    [c1 setArrowsPkg:arr1];
    [c1 GetItemOne];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
Arrow a = (Arrow)[[self arrowsPkg] objectAtIndex:1];
```

with

```
Arrow a = (Arrow)[[[self arrowsPkg] objectAtIndex:1] intValue];
```

or, more clearly written

```
NSNumber *arrowNumber = [[self arrowsPkg] objectAtIndex:1];
Arrow a = [arrowNumber intValue];
```

You are storing your `Arrow` enum types in `NSNumber` in `btn1Clicked:`, so you need to unbox these values in `GetItemOne` from `NSNumber *` types to the earlier `int` values.

Comment: thanks !
may be I need to change the Question.

how can I store enum values ?
ie.like this:

NSMutableArray *arr1=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:aLeft,aLeft,aLeft,aRight,aLeft,aRight, nil];

Some says:
"the right way to do it is not to make the mutable array a property"
what do you think about this title ?[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/816720/whats-the-best-way-to-use-obj-c-2-0-properties-with-mutable-objects-such-as-ns)

Comment: If you're using a recent version of Xcode (and LLVM), you should be able to use the new Objective-C NSNumber boxing syntax, which can be used like this: `[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@(aLeft),@(aRight),nil];`

Comment: finally, I failed to use this style.
WriteByType method's AArrow parameter value always gets weird values.

I wont use a NSMutableArray as a Property
especially with enum values :)

I now prefer as ivar and some getset methods for it manually.

Comment: Here is a solid solution Reporting here. this may save someone's a day in life.

    -(void)GetItemOne
    {
        Arrow a =[[[self arrowsPkg]objectAtIndex:1] intValue];
        [self WriteByType:a];
    
    }

intValue was the keyword.thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`[[self arrowsPkg]objectAtIndex:1]` is an `NSNumber`, not the member of the `Arrow` enum. Just like during the initialization of the `NSNumber` objects, you should convert betweem the object and its enclosed value by calling `intValue` on it.

(And really, re-read a C and Objective-C tutorial. This is **trivial.**)

Comment: thanks for quick response.
wantto get the value in instance objects array property by an index.
ie 0
meant the instance object's ArrowsPkg[0].
so it is aLeft.and it should log "You Get Right Arrow" but it doesn't.

Comment: @N.Ramos And what prvents you from doing that?

Comment: wantto get the value in instance object's array property by an index. ie 0 meant the instance object's ArrowsPkg[0]. so it is aLeft.and it should log "You Get Left Arrow" but it doesn't.

Comment: @N.Ramos After trying my suggestion, it will.

Comment: so, how can I fill with enumerated values instead of pure integer values? would you mind suggesting me a source or book with a page that explains
"how to fill NSMutableArray With enumerated values instead of pure integers or NSIntegers" ?

all I know is assigned enum values are just integers in real.

Comment: @N.Ramos Since "enum values are just integers in real", you can treat them as every other `int`. `[NSNumber numberWithInt:aRight]` is just fine.