# Best practices for mutable collections as properties

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I was planning to use an `NSMutableDictionary` property for storing game data (such as score, settings, etc...).

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableDictionary *gameData;
```

In researching why there is no "mutablecopy" option for properties I found [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/816720/whats-the-best-way-to-use-obj-c-2-0-properties-with-mutable-objects-such-as-ns), for which the accepted answer states:

> the right way to do it is not to make the mutable array a property

What then is the best way to handle mutable collections as properties in modern Objective-C?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is quite a seldom pattern for a class to expose a mutable property for a collection object as it seems to break encapsulation.

Nevertheless there *are* occasions when it might make sense: You could, for example return a KVO proxy for some internally managed collection (using [KVC's `mutableArrayValueForKey:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/mutableArrayValueForKey%3a)).

In these cases is does not really matter whether or not to declare the getter as a property or plain method. In case of properties it should not be a `copy` property, though.

To make this a little clearer here's an example. We have a class that declares a single public getter:

```
@interface Foo : NSObject

@property (strong, readonly) NSMutableArray *publicBars;

@end
```

The implementation manages an encapsulated, private mutable array named `_bars`:

```
@implementation Foo
{
    NSMutableArray *_bars;
}
```

The elements of this array are exposed by [KVC to-many accessors](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/AccessorConventions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002174-SW4):

```
- (NSUInteger)countOfBars
{
    return [_bars count];
}

- (id)objectInBarsAtIndex:(NSUInteger)idx
{
    return _bars[idx];
}

- (void)insertObject:(id)object inBarsAtIndex:(NSUInteger)idx
{
    if (_bars == nil)
        _bars = [NSMutableArray array];
    [_bars insertObject:object atIndex:idx];
}

- (void)removeObjectFromBarsAtIndex:(NSUInteger)idx
{
    [_bars removeObjectAtIndex:idx];
}
```

Here's the fancy part: We are implementing the public property by returning [a KVC proxy that reflects and mutates the internal state](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/mutableArrayValueForKey%3a) without exposing internal ivars. It changes the internal array by only using the public accessors defined above.

```
- (NSMutableArray *)publicBars
{
    return [self mutableArrayValueForKey:@"bars"];
}

@end
```

We can use the proxy to change the internal collection:

```
Foo *foo = [[Foo alloc] init];

NSMutableArray *bars = foo.publicBars;

[bars addObject:@1];
[bars addObject:@2];
[bars removeObjectAtIndex:0];

 // Now the internal _bars array is @[ @2 ].
```

There are actual examples of this and similar patterns in Cocoa. For example there is `-[NSTextView textStorage]` that returns the internal backing store (an object derived from `NSMutableAttributedString`). Though not a collection object this is a mutable object which passes mutations to its host object, the text view.

Comment: I like your idea, but it won't generate KVO notifications for the additions and removals to keyPath publicBars.  It will generate KVO notifications for keyPath bars though.

I struggle with this myself - how to document that a class has a KVC and KVO compliant collection property without actually declaring a property in the interface.  If you had methods like addBars and removeBar in the interface, that might give you a spot to place documentation about the KVO/KVC property, but what if you just want others to be able to observe changes to the collection of bars but not make those changes?

Comment: @Joel Good point. There's no common way to declare KVO compliancy in the header. Im usually going with a comment but it might be nice to have a more "standard" way, like an `NSKVOCompliance` attribute or similar. The static analyzer might even use this to produce warnings for bad observations.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, you can very well use a mutable property - as properties in Objective-C are not only used for encapsulation, but also for memory management (by ARC).

However, you should keep this property in your implementation file, exposing it as a non-mutable, readonly piece of it to other classes.

```
//your_header_file.h

@interface YouClass : NSObject

@property (readonly) NSDictionary *gameState;
@end

//your_implementation_file.m

@interface YouClass ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *gameState;
@end

@implementation SomeClass

//deal with mutable state here


@end
```

**EDIT** :

Also, as mutable collections are usually non thread-safe, be sure you always change them from same thread.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with mutable properties is that other classes can change the contents of the collection **without the owner noticing**. A good design sees that only one class is responsible for a specific task, in this case storing game data.

What I would do is make the mutable dictionary a `strong` private property and provide accessor methods to the outside world in the form of:

```
- (void)storeObject:(id)object forSetting:(NSString *)settingName;
- (id)objectForSetting:(NSString *)settingName;
```

If you really need external classes to be able to **set** the dictionary as a whole, then -- after making sure this really is necessary -- you can still make it a non-mutable property which, when set, creates a new instance of the internal mutable dictionary from the items in the nonmutable dictionary. But I think you should be able to engineer around that necessity.